# SVG icons in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg

I have converted an SVG image into a PathGeometry and saved it as a static resource in my WPF application. I want to display it as an icon on a MenuItem, so I do it like this:

```
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Grid Width="18" Height="18">
                          <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
                                <Path
                                   Fill="DimGray"
                                   Data="{StaticResource ZoomIn}"
                                 />
                          </Viewbox>
                        </Grid>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
```

As I have many MenuItems, and I plan to have more SVG icons, to avoid code duplication I consider creating some UserControl based on the code above that could be utilized like this:

```
<MenuItem.Icon>
 <uc:MyGeometryContainer
   Width="18"
   Height="18"
   Fill="DimGray"
   Geometry="{StaticResource ZoomIn}"/>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```

It's important that this control should have the ability to set its Width, Height and color to customize the icon view.
I got stuck with it, as UserControl exposes its DependencyProperties for a particular DataContext, which means that I will have to create some data object instead of assigning values directly in XAML. I find it awkward.
How would you implement such control?

Comment: "as UserControl exposes its DependencyProperties for a particular DataContext". No, that's not true. If you declare dependency properties in your UserControl, you can set their values directly, either in XAML or code begin. The DataContent would only come into play when you bind a dependency property without explicitly specifying the binding source object.

Comment: Note also that you usually don't need to put a Path control in a Viewbox. It is already able to stretch, see its `Stretch` property. You wouldn't also need the Grid. In the end, you might have no need at all for your UserControl. Just use a Path and set Width, Height, Fill, Stretch and Data.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Clemens' comment, I've exploited Path's Stretch property. The code is now concise, and there's no need for a separate control:

```
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Path
                                    Stretch="Fill"
                                    Width="18"
                                    Height="18"
                                    Fill="DimGray"
                                    Data="{StaticResource ZoomIn}"> 
                                </Path>
                       </MenuItem.Icon>
```